VS Code Border gets purple when loading project from frontend masters
Whenever I clone the project from https://github.com/stevekinney/supertasker.git and open it my VS Code gets a purple border which hurts my eyes. It only happens when I open his projects.
I disabled all the extensions, even when I change the theme directly in VS Code it gets ignored. How to deal with this and get the normal colors of VS Code back?

I see that it's the same in his video, and I can't turn it off:


For anybody that is annoyed as me, he added custom color set in .vscode/settings.json

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"activityBar.activeBackground": "#723aac",
"activityBar.background": "#723aac",
"activityBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
"activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799",
"activityBarBadge.background": "#bf7e40",
"activityBarBadge.foreground": "#15202b",
"commandCenter.border": "#e7e7e799",
"sash.hoverBorder": "#723aac",
"statusBar.background": "#592d86",
"statusBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
"statusBarItem.hoverBackground": "#723aac",
"statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#592d86",
"statusBarItem.remoteForeground": "#e7e7e7",
"titleBar.activeBackground": "#592d86",
"titleBar.activeForeground": "#e7e7e7",
"titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#592d8699",
"titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799"
},
"peacock.color": "#592d86",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
"workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
"workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Default Light Modern"

